# Convert epoch time '1659946913581' to datetime 24hours format in H2 database

Tags: sql, h2

I am using a H2 Database where i need to convert the Epoch to Datetime (24 hours) format. I have the below sample detail.

TABLE: MTTR

COLUMN : END_TIME

VALUE : 1659946913581

I have the below query ,

```
select 
to_char((DATEADD('SECOND', ((END_TIME/ 1000) + 19800), DATE '1970-01-01')), 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss') AS END_TIME_VAL
from MTTR;
```

The issue is that it is giving the incorrect value as '2022-08-08 01:51:53'. It should be '2022-08-08 13:51:53'. What changes can be done here ?

Comment: Since you don't specify a format argument in the call to function `to_char`, I'm guessing that the default format does not use 24 hour time - which it appears is what you want. Therefore I suggest that you add an appropriate format argument to the `to_char` call, i.e. `'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'`

Answer (score 0):

If you expect `2022-08-08 13:51:53`, your time zone has `+05` offset from UTC, so you can use something like

```sql
-- This command isn't needed if your connection already has the proper time zone
SET TIME ZONE '+05';

SELECT END_TIME * INTERVAL '0.001' SECOND + TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 05:00:00' FROM MTTR;
```

in all recent versions of H2 database.